# Adding file under specified folder using maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am using maven assembly plugin to archive the the file under `resources` folder.

main file

```
main-
  src-
    resources-
      -myfiles
```

I am able to archive the file from it. But it is archiving all files under the same path same as

myzip.zip

```
main-
  src-
    resources-
      -myfiles
```

But I want files under `myzip.zip`

```
myzip
  ---myfile
```

not inside hierarchy. 
Below configuration I have used

```
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.file</include>
            </includes>             
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    </assembly>
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

You should add the **outputDirectory** attribute on fileSet pointing to current directory as follow:

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.file</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
</assembly>
```